# IdentityServer4 from .net framework 4.6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, identity, identityserver4

My question is about Identity Server 4 and making calls to it from a pre-existing .net framework MVC application.

I've been through the ID4 "quick starts" as far as getting it run-able and responding correctly to the example .net core MVC application.

As a quick test I created an basic .Net Framework MVC app and created a startup .cs file...

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect;
using Owin;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MVC_OWIN_Client.Startup))]

namespace MVC_OWIN_Client
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            string baseClientAddress = "http://localhost:44301/";

            var authority = JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "Cookies"
            });

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = "mvc.standard",
                Authority = "http://localhost:5000/",
                RedirectUri = baseClientAddress + "signin-oidc",
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = baseClientAddress + "signout-callback-oidc",
                ResponseType = "code id_token",
                Scope = "openid api1 offline_access",

                UseTokenLifetime = false,
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies"
            });
        }
    }
}
```

In ID4 config, I created a client to match...

```
 public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
 {

    ...

    new Client
        {
        ClientId = "mvc.standard",
            ClientName = "MVC Client2",
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,

            ClientSecrets =
            {
                new Secret("secret".Sha256())
            },

            RedirectUris           = { "http://localhost:44301/signin-oidc" },
            PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:44301/signout-callback-oidc" },

            AllowedScopes =
            {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    "api1"
            },
            AllowOfflineAccess = true
    }
};
```

The application will progress through the login and permissions page and ID4 finally indicates the user signed in....

```
info: IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator[0]
      User consented to scopes: openid, api1, offline_access
info: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeCallbackEndpoint[0]
      Authorize endpoint response
      {
        "SubjectId": "2",
        "ClientId": "mvc.standard",
        "RedirectUri": "http://localhost:44301/signin-oidc",
        "State": "OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties=pnxKmthLCWSNS1Tj8sBS1K4K-Erxq8_W3Sfj1gg3zXhTCqP-gKV-Hsfgh_pRLPYQcIdVJONhzA3VMdBNv4xqE7y8uX-pzEmeNKBYb0cPAh6Q9lm5knIS5ds9gccYKubK1U0NpnGAW7tw38brRzD7dEG-EkSgXqjnEGeS4pMCrFaG2CFwq08_-KyA85VufscpT3y9sL0hTLLYYbRiJhWIZBOM427piwaHpR-jbl7KXGo",
        "Scope": "openid api1 offline_access"
      }
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler[10]
      AuthenticationScheme: idsrv signed in.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 152.1613ms 200 text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

That's it.  The MVC Application is never restored, it sits there until it times-out.

Has anyone any experience with Identity Server and able to tell me if there is  something missing from this?  Thanks for your time in advance, Andy.

Comment: Can you explain more what you mean by " it sits there until it times-out."? Your code looks fine

Comment: After the login and permission request pages, the browser goes blank and has the following in the address bar.  "http://localhost:5000/connect/authorize/callback?client_id=mvc.framework&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44301%2Fsignin-...  &x-client-SKU=ID_NET&x-client-ver=1.0.40306.1554"It stays blank until the browser times out.

Comment: That's really weird indeed. You should post a bug in the Identity Server github, they should be able to spot the problem faster

Comment: After the timeout I have http://localhost:44301/signin-oidc in the address bar and ERR_CONNECTION_RESET in the browser.  I've read there's a bug in MS Owin (Katana Bug #197), so I've added a call to app.UseKentorOwinCookieSaver(), but this has no effect either.

Comment: Lol... https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/2059

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone struggling with this and unable to find clear guidance, the answer is to not use UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication at all.  Use WSFederationAuthentication in you .net framework mvc app...

Startup.cs :-

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.WsFederation;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MvcOwinWsFederation.Startup))]

namespace MvcOwinWsFederation
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "Cookies"
            });

            app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
            {
                MetadataAddress = "http://localhost:5000/wsfederation",
                Wtrealm = "urn:owinrp",

                SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies"
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Set up a client for testing in IdentityServer4 as

```
public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
        {
            return new[]
            {
                new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "urn:owinrp",
                    ProtocolType = ProtocolTypes.WsFederation,

                    RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:10313/" },
                    FrontChannelLogoutUri = "http://localhost:10313/home/signoutcleanup",
                    IdentityTokenLifetime = 36000,

                    AllowedScopes = { "openid", "profile" }
                }
            }
         }
```

Make sure identity server 4 has this enabled in its statup.cs...

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();

            var cert = new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "idsrvtest.pfx"), "idsrv3test");

            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddSigningCredential(cert)
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
                .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
                .AddTestUsers(TestUsers.Users)
                **.AddWsFederation();**
...
}
```

Should all work.  Found this here...

https://leastprivilege.com/2017/03/03/extending-identityserver4-with-ws-federation-support/

Andy.

Comment: Open Id connect is protocol, it is supported by all server side technologies, you may get it out of box in some the technologies like asp.net core provide or we need to implement the same. if there is no out of box solution available in asp.net .net framework then we need to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

Use following setup to integrated identity server 4 open Id connect with asp.net MVC .Net Framework cookie base authentication.

Make sure you have install following nuget

Microsoft.Owin.Security

Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies

Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect

Note: update the port number with your application localhost port

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
            {
   app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions {});

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "oidc",
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            Authority = "http://localhost:5000/",
            RedirectUri = "http://localhost:44301/signin-oidc",
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = "http://localhost:44301/signout-callback-oidc",
            ClientId = "CP",
            ResponseType = "id_token",
            Scope = "openid profile",
            UseTokenLifetime = false,
            RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                SecurityTokenValidated = (context) =>
                {
                    var identity = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;
                    var name = identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == identity.NameClaimType)?.Value;

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Your 'solution' doesn't work, yet you vote down a solution that does because it uses ws-federation and was taken from an example by one of the writers of identity server.

Comment: Mention solution is working properly into my application, I think you miss some thing, please share our code for investigate further.

Comment: What do you use as an authorization attribute? I want to enforce policies on controllers and I can't figure out how to do this... :(

Comment: Hi you can use following event and generate authenticate cookie or session to manage the user policy at application level
SecurityTokenValidated = (context) =>
                {
                    var identity = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;
                    var name = identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == identity.NameClaimType)?.Value;
//TODO: generate auth ticket or cookies or session
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }

Answer (score 1):

I have used .NET framework 4.6.1 for creating Web API, For Identity Provider, I am using Identity Server 4 (Earlier I used Identity Server 3). Initially I did face a problem, but I came up with this workaround which worked perfectly to me. **Note that I am using ClientCredentials grantflow.**

I am using the same IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation library for token validation. **The trick is to target to Introspection end point.** Below is my configuration which worked.

Here is the configuration for Web API, **Note that setting setting ValidationMode property is critical here.**

```
app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthServerURI"],
            RequiredScopes = new[] { "comp-read", "stats-read" },
            ClientId = "apiname",
            ClientSecret = "apisecret",
            ValidationMode = ValidationMode.ValidationEndpoint,
            EnableValidationResultCache = true
        });
```

This is how the APIResource and Client is configured in my IDP.

```
new ApiResource
            {
                Name = "apiname",
                DisplayName = "Web API",
                Description = "Access to Web API Services",
                ApiSecrets = new List<Secret> {new Secret("apisecret".Sha256())},
                Scopes = new List<Scope> {
                    new Scope("comp-read", "Read access to Comp Db API"),
                    new Scope("stats-read", "Read access to Stats API")
                }
```

This is how one of the client is configured.

```
new Client
            {
                ClientName = "name of the client",
                ClientId = "clientname",
                Enabled = true,
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
                ClientSecrets = new List<Secret> {
                    new Secret("secretforclient".Sha256())
                },
                AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                {
                    "stats-read"
                },
                AccessTokenLifetime = 1000
            }
```

Hopefully this helps. Thanks.

Comment: Using IdentityServer4, you cannot use the IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation any more, it compiles fine, but won't load beacause of some internal problem with version/references. So how to do this without the reference to the IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation NuGet?

Comment: I am using it. it works like a Gem. My API is written using .NET Framework 4.6.1. In this project I am using IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation to validate a token generated from IdentityServer4's Introspection end point.

Comment: I have been unable to find any working samples. I have a web UI (MVC) and the controllers are calling another API (rest/json). I need to protect the web UI with Identity Server 4 and parse the token from the controllers in the Web UI to the rest/json API. All in. NET 4.x. But I cannot find anywhere with working samples or get it to work. I struggled for days now. But if you got it to work with Identity Server 3 NuGet package, I will give it another go.

Comment: @Vinay I tried your solution but I still get Unauthorized error

Comment: @nivs1978 did you manage to solve this or any working example if u remember

Comment: @Prany Yes, I will try to find the sample on Monday. However I found that WinForm can be compiled in .Net 6, so that makes things more easy. However I will find a working .Net 4.6 sample,for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated (2020) example on how to implement IndentityServer4 in NET4.6, including PKCE.

Blog: [Refreshing your Legacy ASP.NET IdentityServer Client Applications (with PKCE)](https://www.scottbrady91.com/ASPNET/Refreshing-your-Legacy-ASPNET-IdentityServer-Client-Applications)
Github: [ScottBrady91.BlogExampleCode.AspNetPkce](https://github.com/scottbrady91/Blog-Example-Classes/tree/13ba4677407887a823ec1710a3b2c9a31ca9b19b/AspNetFrameworkPkce/ScottBrady91.BlogExampleCode.AspNetPkce)

The PKCE bit is too long to copy, but the basic config is as follows. Note, there are **NO** `signin-oidc` / `signout-callback-oidc` suffixes in the URL configuration!

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "cookie"
        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = "mvc.owin",
            Authority = "http://localhost:5000",
            RedirectUri = "http://localhost:5001/",
            ResponseType = "code id_token",
            Scope = "openid profile api1",

            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "cookie",

            UseTokenLifetime = false,

            RedeemCode = true,
            SaveTokens = true,
            ClientSecret = "secret"
        });
    }
}
```